# Functional Analysis - Supplemental Lecture Series Request

Tags: functional-analysis, lecture-notes

Can anybody point me in the direction of a good lecture series on Functional Analysis?

I'm currently taking the class(we're using Conway). But, with it being online(thanks COVID), I'm struggling to get a good grasp on it because our lectures are prerecorded and don't allow for those classroom interactions that would otherwise clarify and demystify the material.

Thus far, these are the only 3 I've found, that are remotely decent:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLo4jXE-LdDTTIIIRwqK35CbFJieSJEcVR

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IyH9LgOw5s4&list=PLp0hSY2uBeP8fav3g6SNIYnt-00klqmx9

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IIw_U8rv4Q&list=PL554B877A872B4F94

Comment: Well, I doubt that static prerecorded lectures are going to help with problems derived from static prerecorded lectures. In this day and age, isn't office hours the perfect solution for you?

Alternatively searching up course pages for their resources is what I used to do. Try this for example? There are homeworks with solutions and lecture notes.

https://www.math.uzh.ch/gorodnik/fa17/index.html

Comment: Yes, office hours would be the best solution... If the professor would provide some examples for context or provide us with concrete analogies that we can build on. 

Unfortunately, he just points us back to the lecture notes, book, and videos(which are of him reading the notes- literally, the notes are on the screen and he reads them almost verbatim- and filling in some of the details).

Also, thank you for the notes, I'll for sure be reading these.

Comment: Asking questions here can provide you will some interaction as well, especially if you use a chatroom.  The list of chatrooms can be found here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26814/list-of-chatrooms and the "Modern Abstract Analysis" might work well for you